# How to display last N characters of a C string?

Tags: c++11

I'm trying to do some programming homework but I cant figure out how to display the last N characters of a C string. This is my attempt at it so far. I am also supposed to ask for the number of characters and validate it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
void choice_4(char str[]) {
    int characters;
    cout << "How many characters from the end of the string do you want to display? ";
    cin >> characters;
    if (str[characters] != '\0')
        cout<<str.Substring(str.length - characters,characters)
}
```

Comment: Is this a C or C++ question? Also, C-strings do not have member functions.

Comment: Don't want to feed you an answer but here's something I'd consider helpful: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/

Comment: Either you can use C string functions to look at the C string or you can just make a C++ std::string from the C string and then you can use std::string member functions.

Answer (score 1):

As usual with homework questions, I won't give a solution but a few hints.

- I assume by “validate” you mean check whether the string is long enough. For example, you cannot show the last 12 characters of a string that is only 7 characters long. Your current attempt looking at the *n*-th byte of the string cannot work, however. If the string is shorter than *n* bytes, you'll index it out of range and invoke undefined behavior. If it is longer – which is perfectly valid and, in fact, will be the case except for trivial cases – your test wrongly returns that the requested length is invalid.
- What you should do instead is computing the length *N* of the string and then test whether *n* ≤ *N*. You can use the standard library function [`std::strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) to obtain the length of a NUL terminated character array. Or you can loop it yourself and count how many bytes you see until the first NUL byte.
- A C-style string is just a pointer to a byte in memory with the implicit contract that any bytes up to the first NUL byte that follow it belong to the string. Therefore, if you add *m* ≤ *N* to the pointer, you get the sub-string starting at the *m*-th (zero-based) byte.
- Therefore, in order to get the sub-string with the *last* *n* characters of a string with *N* characters, how do you determine *m*?

By the way: A NUL byte is a `char` with the integer value 0. You can encode it as `'\0'` (as you did) but `0` works perfectly fine, too.